# Django: How to save data to db using SessionWizardView in Django 1.7?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-formwizard

I've been trying to use the SessionWizardView for a multi-step form for a long registration process. I'm using 2 ModelForms and using instance on initialization.

This is the source code:
https://djangosnippets.org/snippets/1078/

Documentation tells me to do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list) but not able to save data here too.

```
class ContactWizard(SessionWizardView):
    def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
        do_something_with_the_form_data(form_list)
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

Q: How to save data to db using SessionWizardView in Django 1.7?

Answer (score 0):

The form_list argument of the `done` method is a list of form objects that are part of the wizard (stored in the wizard instance's self.form_list attribute).

If you have a wizard made with two modelforms, form_list will have two modelform instances.

Probably what you want to do is call the "save" method on these modelforms.

The form_list attribute is an OrderedDict. I'm not sure if it always the case but using a NamedUrlWizard, the forms are also inside of tuples (url_name, form_object).

So in order to call the `save()` method on each form you might do:

```
def done(self, form_list, **kwargs):
    for form in self.form_list.items():
        form[-1].save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/page-to-redirect-to-when-done/')
```

By the way, the snippet you linked to did get added to django in contrib.formtools, which comes with either cookie or session storage. However django 1.8 this package has been split out to [django-formtools](https://github.com/django/django-formtools).